# Using HTML5 "data-" attributes with MVC3 and Html.ActionLink<TController>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, html

So it seems that the non-generic overload of `Html.ActionLink()` works nicely with HTML5 `data-` attributes by renaming attributes with underscores into attributes with hyphens:

[How to use dashes in HTML-5 data-* attributes in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520487/how-to-use-html-5-data-attributes-in-asp-net-mvc)

But, this doesn't seem to work for the strongly-typed `Html.ActionLink<TController>()`.

So, the link for JQuery Mobile

```
@(Html.ActionLink<HomeController>(
     c => c.Index(), 
     "Home",  
      new { data_direction="reverse" } ))
```

gives an HTML source of

```
<a data_direction="reverse" href="/" class="ui-link">Home</a>
```

which is not what I want.

Any ideas? There's no overload that takes a `RouteValueDictionary` so that route is out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So it seems that there's a bug (feature?) in the `Microsoft.Web.Mvc` extension method on `HtmlHelper.ActionLink<TController>`. My workaround is:

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;
using System.Web.Routing;
using Authentication;

public static class LinkExtensions
{

    // Named thusly to avoid conflict, I anticipate a search-and-replace later!
    public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink5<TController>(this HtmlHelper helper, Expression<Action<TController>> action, string linkText, object htmlAttributes) where TController : Controller
    {
        RouteValueDictionary routeValuesFromExpression = Microsoft.Web.Mvc.Internal.ExpressionHelper.GetRouteValuesFromExpression<TController>(action);
        return helper.RouteLink(linkText, routeValuesFromExpression, HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes));
    }
}
```

which when called with

```
@(Html.ActionLink5<HomeController>(
    c => c.Index(), 
    "Home",  
    new { data_direction="reverse" } ))
```

appears to work just fine...