# @Html.ActionLink with ko data-bind

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

First, is it possible to use `@Html.ActionLink` with knockout binding?

If yes, how would I write that?

This is what I need:

```
@Html.ActionLink( [I want display QuestionID() - a ko view model property] , "Question [controller action name]", "Project [controller name]", new { project = [here should be ProjectID() - a ko view model property]  id = [here should be QuestionID() - a ko view model property] }, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "data-bind", "title: 'View detailed question page'" } }))
```

In simple words, it should look like below when it renders:

> https://plus.google.com/photos/105612417165831662125/albums/5847070406315217649?authkey=CPqQ2oGYn46GFQ

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your link just go to an image of a URL?

Comment: Yes. It's hosted on google+ and it should be a public image.

Comment: But why link to an image of text? Couldn’t you just include the text in your question?

Comment: Not enough reputation on stackoverflow, so can't upload an image..  by the way, data_bind did work for text, title, etc html attributes, but I am still not able to pass parameters on my URL, so still trying to fix that... research is still on!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can of course include `data-bind` attributes in an ActionLink; look at [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520487/how-to-use-html-5-data-attributes-in-asp-net-mvc) for how to do that. But keep in mind that Knockout is purely client-side, and so you'll need to make some kind of AJAX request when you want Knockout to talk to MVC.