# Provide value to htmlAttributes where keys contain dash in their name in MVC view (e.g. "data-bind")

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, html

Most of the Html helpers available in ASP.Net MVC have overloads with `object htmlAttributes`. This is used to provide additional attribute values for the outputted tags. While using the anonymous object notation for specifying htmlAttributes value, their property names must be valid c# identifier.

Now the problem arises when you are trying to output a property with a dash `-` character (for e.g. knockout js's "data-bind" attribute)

So for example lets take the following example:

```
@Html.TextBox("Title", string.Empty, new { data-bind="text: title" })
```

Try the above code in your view and at run-time it would show error screen with below message:

```
Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS0746: Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.
```

So the question is, how to provide htmlAttributes with their property keys having dash characters; like "data-bind"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use HTML-5 data-\* attributes in ASP.NET MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520487/how-to-use-html-5-data-attributes-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your property names, replace all your dash `-` characters with an underscore `_` (as shown in example below):

```
@Html.TextBox("Title", string.Empty, new { data_bind="text: title" })
```

This would work because all HTML helpers convert an underscore `_` in a property name to a dash `-` when rendering the HTML; i.e. for your example, `data_bind` when outputted in html gets converted to `data-bind`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not always correct.  Say you're using parameters in a URL.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add Job", "Index", "Home", new { foo_bar = "foobar" }, new { @class = "btn btn-default", data_foo = "bar" })
```

The data_foo does get rendered as "data-foo", but the parameters stays as a under bar. Your result will be: `http://your.domain/yourapp/?foo_bar=foobar`

Of course you can't actually use the dash or you get the error specified in the OP.

I have worked around this as follows, but I'd be interested to see if anyone that comes along in the future will have a better way:

```
@{
   var link = Html.ActionLink("Add Job", "Index", "Home", new { foo_bar = "foobar" }, new { @class = "btn btn-default", data_foo = "bar" });
}

@Html.Raw(link.ToString().Replace('_', '-'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes` method. The following code will add a tooltip to the text input box, with the tooltip displaying the data from the DisplayAttribute description for MyIntVal on my model.

```
@{
    var htmlAttributesWithDashes =  HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(
        new
        {
            id = "myTextBoxId",
            data_toggle = "tooltip",
            data_position = "left top",
            title = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression( m => m.MyIntVal, ViewData ).Description
        }
        );


}

<div class="col-sm-6">
    @Html.TextBoxFor( m => m.MyIntVal, htmlAttributesWithDashes )
</div>
```