# Knockout data-bind attribute in razor syntax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, knockout.js

I have Html written in Razor syntax:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.AllBetStatuses.Count; ++i)
{
    <li class="betReportingCheckbox">
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.AllBetStatuses[i].Checked, new { @class =   
         "betStatusCheckboxes"})
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.AllBetStatuses[i].Name)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.AllBetStatuses[i].Value)
    </li>
}
```

I want to use knockout.js to bind these values, but when I try something of this type:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.AllBetStatuses[i].Checked, new { @class =   
         "betStatusCheckboxes", @data-bind="..."})
```

I get a syntax error, because the '-' character is not valid there. Is there any simple way to do this using Razor syntax?

Comment: did you try ...,"data-bind" = "..."... ? (or ...,data-bind = "..."...)

Comment: iirc, it should just be: `data_bind="..."`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use HTML-5 data-\* attributes in ASP.NET MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520487/how-to-use-html-5-data-attributes-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Replace the '-' by an '_'

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.AllBetStatuses[i].Checked, new { @class =   
     "betStatusCheckboxes", @data_bind="..."})
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: I figured it out later, but when I returned here you already had the answer so I'll mark your solution.