# ASP.NET MVC Adding Attribute "data-message" to Html.TextBoxFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Using MVC 4 I create a text box for a model property with the "data-message" attribute:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(o => o.TradeOrder.Symbol, new {data-message="Required"})
```

However, I get the following error:

> Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must
>   be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.

Comment: here is a link with more information http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520487/how-to-use-html-5-data-attributes-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Use `_`:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(o => o.TradeOrder.Symbol, new {data_message="Required"})
```

The TextBoxFor helper will know what to do and replace it with `-` when generating the markup.

Comment: Thanks @Darin and shame on MVC to not handling this little things!

Comment: Although correct, one thing I found is that the case is not preserved. data_maxDate renders as data-maxdate. I haven't figured out how to fix this. I want to use data attributes to pass as properties off to a JQuery plugin so the case must match.