# Using knockout binding with razor syntax

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, knockout.js

I am wondering if it is possible to use a **Knockout** `data-bind` within **Razor** syntax.

I have this code in my view:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: relays">
    <tr>
        <td id="body-button-column">
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" title="Remove relay" data-bind="click: $parent.removeRelay">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></i>
            </button>
        </td>
        <td><input type="text" data-bind="value: $index"/></td>
        <td>@Html.DropDownList("RelayConfigurations[" + $index + "].Address", Model.Addresses, "Select an Item")</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

And my viewmodel has the following property

```
self.relays = ko.observableArray(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.RelayConfigurations)));
```

where the RelayConfigurations is a collection object on the model.

In the line using the Razor syntax `@Html.DropDownList`.... I would like to use a knockout binding for the $index value but am not sure how to do that.  Or if it is even possible.

If I replace the `$index` in that line with a hard-coded value of zero, the model binding in the controller action works as expected on **Postback** (albeit only the first relay in the collection has any data because of the hard-coded value of zero).

Comment: I'm sure you are already know this but, Razor is a server side technology and Knockoutjs is a client side technology.  While it can be done and done very well, sometimes you may be better off choosing one or the other to achieve the final result of displaying and capturing data on page.

Comment: Understood.  The reason I am choosing to mix them is because the list of relay configurations is a dynamically sized list that the user can add to and remove from.  Using Knockout observable array seemed to be the cleanest and most efficient way to manage the dynamically sized list while updating the UI.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issues as i understand it

1. Getting the html into a format that will be easily accepted as a server-side model when the form is submitted.
2. The ability to add items to the dropdownList from the client side.

A solution to the first issue is to look at the rendered HTML of the DropdownList and copying the resulting `<select>` tag then applying `knockoutjs` to that, that way you will keep the same format that the server is expecting to be able to turn the submitted form back into the server side model while taking advantage of knockoutjs

so you will end up with something like this

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: relays">
    <tr>
        <td id="body-button-column">
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" title="Remove relay" data-bind="click: $parent.removeRelay">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></i>
            </button>
        </td>
        <td><input type="text" data-bind="value: $index"/></td>
        <td>
           <select data-bind="attr: {id : 'RelayConfigurations[' + $index + '].Address' }, options: relays ,optionsCaption:'Select an Item'"></select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

As for the second issue, you already have the data to `data-bind` to, so you can add and remove items as necessary.

From @meyousikmann comment below

Just a quick correction on the syntax for anyone else coming to this answer:

```
<select data-bind="attr: {name: 'RelayConfigurations[' + $index() + '].Address'}, options: $parent.addresses, optionsCaption: 'Select an Item'"></select>
```

Comment: Well, that is another way to do it.  Not using Razor syntax, but worked anyway.  Just a quick correction on the syntax for anyone else coming to this answer: <select data-bind="attr: {name: 'RelayConfigurations[' + $index() + '].Address'}, options: $parent.addresses, optionsCaption: 'Select an Item'"></select>.  Thanks for the pointer in the right direction.  Still would be interested to know if it can be done with Razor syntax.

Comment: I doubt that there will be an effective way to do this sort of thing.  The problem is that Razor and knockout know nothing about the existence each other.  You could try looking into http://knockoutmvc.com . I haven't used it myself but might be worth a look.

Comment: Downvoted because it doesn't actually provide an answer to the question but an alternative workaround.

Comment: The issue is that Razor runs on the server and knockout runs on the browser/client. There is no easy way for Razor to know about knockout. or for knockout to know about Razor. They are fundamentally different technologies trying to achieve a similar result.

Answer (score 6):

Of course you can use knockout in razor :)

I believe what you are looking for is this anonymous object method:

```
@Html.DropDownList("somelist", Model.List, new { id = "listbox", data_bind = "" })
```

Comment: Thanks for your response; however, I have two problems.  The syntax shown does not work.  I can't use 'data-bind' where you've indicated.  Intellisense says the symbol cannot be resolved.  Second, in order for the MVC model binder to work correctly, the form field name has to match the name of the model property.  Razor syntax for DropDownList says the first argument is for the name.  That is the argument that I want to use data binding.  In the code in my original post, I was trying to indicate where I needed to do the data binding with the $index symbol in the first argument to DropDownList.

Comment: Correct, I have forgotten that dashes can be hairy. This method should work if you use data_bind, read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520487/how-to-use-html-5-data-attributes-in-asp-net-mvc.