# Action Link with Javascript and pass value to controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using action link in my application.

I am having some requirement to call javascript on it's click event.

I know that I can do that using following code.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Home","Index","Main",new{@onclick="OnIndexCall"});
```

Now on the click event of action link I am computing two values in function and i also need to pass that values to the page in which I am redirecting.

I don't know how can I do that.

**Please is there any way to pass the calculated value in from javascript function to redirection page?**

**EDIT :-**

```
function OnIndexCall(){
    var a=10;
    var b=a+20;
}
```

Now i need to pass these "a" and "b" values to the redirection page.

Comment: share your javascript code also.

Comment: @Nirav Kamani please create a click event. don't try to do this as inline method, see the link for similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28739962/cannot-pass-parameters-from-view-to-controller-by-using-javascript/28744490#28744490

Comment: @FrebinFrancis Thanks but i don't want to use ajax and window.location. I only want to use actionlink nothing else.... thanks for suggestion...

Comment: You can use jquery to reconstruct the url, adding the query string parameters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass data through QueryString as shown :-

```
@Html.ActionLink("Home","Index","Main",new{ @onclick="OnIndexCall(this)" });

function OnIndexCall(elem){
    var a=10;
    var b=a+20;
    $(elem).attr('href', $(elem).attr('href') + '?a=' + a + '&b=' + b);
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g294yt6q/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Create two hidden fields in form. assign values before submiting form may be on onClick event. so you will get those values in HttpPost action.

By this way your values will not be show in URL(Query String)

HTML

```
<a href="/Main/Index" onclick="return OnIndexCall(this)">Home</a>
<form type="post" action="URL" id="myform">
  <input type="hidden" name="a" id="a">
  <input type="hidden" name="b" id="b">
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
function OnIndexCall(elem){
    var a=10;
    var b=a+20;
    $("#a").val(a);
    $("#b").val(b);
    $("#myform").submit();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You cant redirect using an ajax call (ajax calls stay on the same page)