# Html.ActionLink instead of Button for Modal popup

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I have a button that triggers the Modal popup using Button

```
<button class="list-group-item md-trigger" data-modal="selectform">
                            Select Employee</button>
```

But when I try to use ActionLink it DOES NOT POPUP the window

```
@Html.ActionLink("Select Employee", "", "", null, new { 
        @datamodal = "selectform", @class = "list-group-item md-trigger" })
```

Comment: To mimic the attributes in your button, it would need to be `new { data-modal = "selectform", .... }`

Comment: it does not like the hyphen thats why i end-up putting together and here is what the error says `Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.`

Comment: @AbuHamzah, Sorry, its `new { data_modal = "selectform", ... }` (the razor engine converts the underscore to a hyphen)

Comment: tried no error this time with `data-Modal` but it does not popup the window

Comment: tried like this `@Html.ActionLink("Select Employee", "", "", null, new { data-modal = "selectform", @class = "list-group-item   md-trigger" })` same error message which i posted above

Comment: does not matter `data-Modal` or `data-modal` same error message

Comment: tried `data_model ` no error but does not pop-up the window

Comment: Ack... `data_modal` not `data_model`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use HTML-5 data-\* attributes in ASP.NET MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520487/how-to-use-html-5-data-attributes-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: sorry it was typo but yes `data_modal` still does not popup

Comment: Stephen Muecke is correct, use data_modal. What does the rendered html look like? The html helper creates an <a> tag not a button tag. Are you sure an <a> tag will show your modal?