# Kendo Grid - Select row and display values related to row

Tags: javascript, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am working on a simple project to display a list of things in a Kendo Grid.
When the user clicks a row of the Kendo Grid, I want to display values that are related to that row.

So far the grid works fine. It became selectable and its mouse-click event fires a JavaScript function.

Grid looks like this:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<MyProject.Models.Object>()
    .BindTo((IEnumerable<MyProject.Models.Object>)Model)
    .Name("Object")
    .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(p => p.ObjectID).Title("ID").Hidden().HtmlAttributes(new { id="ID" });
            columns.Bound(p => p.DmObjectName.DmObjectNameDesc).Title("Object Name");
            columns.Bound(p => p.DmObjectType.DmObjectTypeDesc).Title("Object Type");
            columns.Bound(p => p.DmObjectState.DmObjectStateDesc).Title("Storage State");
        })
    .Pageable(pager => pager
        .PageSizes(new[] { 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 1000 })) 
        .Filterable(ftb => ftb.Mode(GridFilterMode.Row))
        .Selectable(selectable => selectable
        .Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single)
        .Type(GridSelectionType.Row)
    )
    .Sortable()
    .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
    .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
    .ColumnMenu()
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Server()
            .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.ObjectID)
        ))
    .Events(e => e.Change("Grid_OnRowSelect"))
)
```

And label and textboxes:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend accesskey="H">Object Detail</legend>
    <table border="0" style="width: 95%; margin: 0 auto; border-collapse: collapse; border: 0px solid black;">
        <tr>
            <td class="label">
                @Html.Label("Object Name:", new { @class = "designschema" })
            </td>
            <td class="editor">
                @Html.Kendo().MaskedTextBox().Name("ObjectName").Enable(false)
            </td>
            <td class="label">
                @Html.Label("Max:", new { @class = "designschema" })
            </td>
            <td class="editor">
                @Html.Kendo().MaskedTextBox().Name("Max").Enable(false)
            </td>
            <td class="label">
                @Html.Label("Avg:", new { @class = "designschema" })
            </td>
            <td class="editor">
                @Html.Kendo().MaskedTextBox().Name("Avg").Enable(false)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">
                @Html.Label("Fire", new { @class = "designschema" })
            </td>
            <td class="editor">
                @Html.Kendo().MaskedTextBox().Name("Fire").Enable(false)
            </td>
            <td class="label">
                @Html.Label("State", new { @class = "designschema" })
            </td>
            <td class="editor">
                @Html.Kendo().MaskedTextBox().Name("State").Enable(false)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">
                @Html.Label("Health", new { @class = "designschema" })
            </td>
            <td class="editor">
                @Html.Kendo().MaskedTextBox().Name("Health").Enable(false)
            </td>
            <td class="label">
                @Html.Label("Location", new { @class = "designschema" })
            </td>
            <td class="editor">
                @Html.Kendo().MaskedTextBox().Name("Location").Enable(false)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">
                @Html.Label("Reactivity", new { @class = "designschema" })
            </td>
            <td class="editor">
                @Html.Kendo().MaskedTextBox().Name("Reactivity").Enable(false)
            </td>
            <td class="label">
                @Html.Label("Container", new { @class = "designschema" })
            </td>
            <td class="editor">
                @Html.Kendo().MaskedTextBox().Name("Container").Enable(false)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">
                @Html.Label("Special", new { @class = "designschema" })
            </td>
            <td class="editor">
                @Html.Kendo().MaskedTextBox().Name("Special").Enable(false)
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
    <legend accesskey="N">Notes</legend>
    <table border="0" style="width: 95%; margin: 0 auto; border-collapse: collapse; border: 0px solid black;">
        <tr>
            <td class="editor">
                @Html.TextArea("Notes", new { @style = "resize: vertical; width: 100%; height: 20px" })
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</fieldset>
```

And here is the JavaScript:

```
<script>
    function Grid_OnRowSelect() {
        var row = this.select();
        var id = row.data("ID");
    }
</script>
```

I have not worked beyond this at the moment because it seems that `row.data("ID")` isn't working. I ran my application in debug mode and caught what is in the `var row`.

The value of `row` looks like this:

```
<tr class="k-state-selected" aria-selected="true">
    <td id="ID" style="display:none">1</td>
    <td>TEST</td>
    <td>Object (Flammable)</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

So the selected values from row are correct. But is there a good way to pick each value from `<td>, <tr>`? Or a good way to use `row.data("ID")`?

I also want to put selected values into the textboxes right below the Kendo Grid. And I was thinking there is a way to select model, instead of each values from Grid, which name is `MyProject.Models.Object` where `ID` is matching to model.

Would you give me some good way to approach and solve so I can move further?

Comment: You want data-id, not data("ID")?  http://www.telerik.com/forums/creating-data-bound-html-attributes-in-mvc-grid-cells

Comment: another link with a bunch of info it looks like for data attributes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520487/how-to-use-html-5-data-attributes-in-asp-net-mvc/4515095#4515095

Comment: One more http://www.telerik.com/forums/creating-data-bound-html-attributes-in-mvc-grid-cells

Comment: Can I suggest a solution using Jquery?

Comment: Yes, please, any suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You could try kendo grid dataItem function. In your case it will be:

```
var selectedItem = this.dataItem(this.select());
```

Comment: I tried this before. And getting this error _Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined_

Comment: "this" is your grid object ? You could try to get reference to grid by $("#Object").data("kendoGrid"). Try use it instead "this

Comment: Yes, I did it also. I did `var grid = $("#Object").data("kendoGrid");
var selectedItem = grid.dataItem(grid.select());` and it referenced from http://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-get-selected-row-and-its-dataitem

Answer (score 0):

This is [documented](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#methods-dataItem):

> When using the Grid's MVC wrapper, the Grid must be Ajax-bound for the dataItem() method to work. When using server binding, the dataSource instance does not contain the serialized data items.

You are using `BindTo`, so the grid's html is rendered at the server and it is not bound to any data at client-side. You can use a `DataSource`, or you need to do everything manually.